# struct sigaction's sa_mask field and sigprocmask() function

Tags: c

struct sigaction:

```
struct sigaction {
       void      (*sa_handler)(int);   /* addr of signal handler, */
                                       /* or SIG_IGN, or SIG_DFL */
       sigset_t sa_mask;               /* additional signals to block */
       int      sa_flags;              /* signal options, Figure 10.16 */

       /* alternate handler */
       void     (*sa_sigaction)(int, siginfo_t *, void *);
    };
```

sigprocmask function:

```
   int sigprocmask(int how, const sigset_t *restrict set, sigset_t *restrict oset);
```

is that both `sa_mask` of `struct sigaction` and `sigprocmask()` function are able to mask the signal? what is the difference?

Comment: Have you read the [manual page for `sigprocmask`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigprocmask.2.html)? It allows you to combine the currently set mask with another mask, without having to call `sigaction` to reset the whole signal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mask in `struct sigaction` are signals that will be blocked (in the thread the signal handler executes in) while the signal handler is running.

The mask established with sigprocmask() are the signals that will be blocked for the process (and should only be used in a single threaded program)

Comment: For multi-threaded programs, `pthread_sigmask` can be used.